# Assigned client certificate is ignored when TLS connection established

Tags: c#, x509certificate, tls1.2

As in this question [Connecting to a Web Service using Client Certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049845/connecting-to-a-web-service-using-client-certificate-authentication) I am trying to call a SOAP web service from c# using a client certificate supplied by the server admin. Just as in that question, I can access the web service with the provided certificate in the browser just fine (he used CURL, I can use IE **but not FF**). I have ascertained that the same cert is used in the browser and in the code below and that the server supports TLS 1.2 unlike in the linked question - that is the only thing that makes my question different.

The cert has been imported into `My` and `Root` stores and I can ascertain that it is being found and assigned to the WS object instance before making the WS method call.

But in the trace I can see that it is being ignored:

> System.Net Information: 0 : [5928]
>   TlsStream#11958757::.ctor(host=wsuat.domain.com, #certs=0)

The code I am using is very simple, I inherited it from the previous developers and was told that it "used to work" about 1 year ago. With the certificate assignment line commented out it works fine locally, but as soon as I try to access the WS on the server with two-way SSL turned on, it fails:

```
using (ASoapClient client = new ASoapClient())
{
    try
    {
        //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
             StoreLocation.LocalMachine
            ,StoreName.Root // also can load from .My
            ,X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber // also can find by SubjectName
            ,"FA33.........................634"
        );
        SubmitResult rr = client.Submit(req);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error submitting");
    }
}
```

When I set `Expect100Continue` to `true` I get the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://wsuat.domain.com/wsuat/ws.asmx.
This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

When I comment that out, I get the following:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'wsuat.domain.com'.
---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And as often happens, as soon as I asked this question in total desperation, the answer was found. Looked up `basicHttpBinding` security mode in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and found a mention of transport `clientCredentialType` attribute.

Once I added the `transport` element and set it to `Certificate` as follows, everything worked:

```
  <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
  </security>
```