# Call SOAP with ssl certificate using C#

Tags: c#, soap

I need to call a third party webservice (SOAP) from c# application. Webservice expects us to send a certificate. I have .crt, .jks & .pem files, how can use these certificates and call SOAP.

Below is my current code

```
SOAPServiceClient client = new SOAPServiceClient();

using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    // Add a HTTP Header to an outgoing request
    HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    requestMessage.Headers["TrustedUser"] = "abc";
    requestMessage.Headers["Account"] = "def";
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name]
       = requestMessage;
}

X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import("PATH_TO_CERT", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

var result = await client.FetchDetailsAsync(filterType.CUSTOMER, "1234");
```

I am getting below error

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'X509Certificate is immutable on this platform. Use the equivalent constructor instead.'
```

I am able to call API using SOAP UI tool after including certificate in the request but not with c#.

How to call SOAP api using c# with SSL certificate?

Comment: Check this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049845/connecting-to-a-web-service-using-client-certificate-authentication) and notice the `client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate`